# Azure Pipeline VSTest@2 Task thinks project that ends with "Tester" is a test project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**My YAML:**

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'


variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

I have a csproj called `DatabaseModeler Tester`:

[image]

When the pipeline runs, I get these errors:

[image]

This project is **not** a test project, nor does it have any test dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value of the VsTest task is:

```
        {
            "name": "testAssemblyVer2",
            "type": "multiLine",
            "label": "Test files",
            "defaultValue": "**\\*test*.dll\n!**\\*TestAdapter.dll\n!**\\obj\\**",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "Run tests from the specified files.<br>Ordered tests and webtests can be run by specifying the .orderedtest and .webtest files respectively. To run .webtest, Visual Studio 2017 Update 4 or higher is needed. <br><br>The file paths are relative to the search folder. Supports multiple lines of minimatch patterns. [More information](https://aka.ms/minimatchexamples)",
            "groupName": "testSelection",
            "properties": {
                "rows": "3",
                "resizable": "true"
            },
            "visibleRule": "testSelector = testAssemblies"
        },
```

<sup>https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VsTestV2/task.json#L72</sup>

Note that the task will pick up any assembly that has "test" in its name.

```
            "defaultValue": "**\\*test*.dll\n!**\\*TestAdapter.dll\n!**\\obj\\**",
```

Setting the `testAssemblyVer2` property on the VsTest2 task will allow you to pick the right test assemblies.

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    testAssemblyVer2: "**\\*test*.dll\n!**\\*TestAdapter.dll\n!**\\obj\\**\n!**\Tester*.dll",
```

In this case I added a specific exclusion for `Tester*.dll`: `\n!**\Tester*.dll`, but you can also create a more specific rule to select your test assumblies based on your solution's folder structure, for example when your tests all sit in the `tests` folder:

```
"**\\tests\\*test*.dll"
```